# Including Empty Text in TFS HTML Field (TFS 2013)

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

I am trying to add default empty text to an HTML field in TFS 2013. I am doing this by updating the "EmptyText" attribute for the field in the Layout options (using Process Editor).

However, regardless of what I enter here, the intended text is never displayed. It is always empty. I have the same issue with both HTML & Plain Text fields.

Is this a fundamental limitation of TFS? Or am I specifying this incorrectly?

*I am not using a **DEFAULT** rule because I want the user to notice that the field is empty and be required to enter a value.*

Comment: Which environment are you testing, web access or Team explorer? And are you setting this property on a system field or a custom field?

Comment: I am testing web access (Visual Studio Online, TFS 2013). Using a custom field, but have tested with a system field as well with the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

I can get it work correctly. Two changes made:

1. Edit the "Empty Text" attribute just as you mentioned above (in my case I create one custom HTML field called Custom.DetailHTML):
   [image]
2. Add Required rule to this field to define that this field must be specified with a value:

```html
<FieldDefinition name="DetailHtml" refname="Custom.DetailHtml" type="HTML">
  <REQUIRED />
</FieldDefinition>
```

If you still can't get it work, please show your WIT file.

Comment: I'm doing something almost identical, though I set the field to Required only at a particular state transition. Still, I tried to set the Required rule to the Field as you mention, but have the same result where the "Empty Text" is not displayed.

Comment: Currently I can't post images due to my meager reputation, but the notable differences from your screen capture are as follows: Dock: Fill, Label Position: Top, Type: HtmlFieldControl. When I switch those to match yours, then YES, I do see the empty text, however, the field is no longer an HTML box. This appears to be the key limitation: If the field control is of type HTMLFieldControl, it will not display any Empty Text specification.

Comment: @NickZ, I still can't reproduce your issue on my side. If I change Type to HTMLFieldControl, the Empty Text shows correctly as well. So, 1). I suspect maybe there is something wrong with your WIT file, if possible, it is better if you can share it (you can upload it to OneDrive and post back the link). 2). Or maybe it is just a client issue, ask your team members to have a try.

Comment: here is the XML file for the WIT: [link](http://1drv.ms/1F9VeaZ). I will also check whether this is a client issue, but won't be able to confirm for a couple of weeks.